# Is it possible to add column to AbpAuditLogs table?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

It is possible to add column to AbpAuditLogs table?
for example we want to add ErrorCode to AbpAuditLogs table. If possible, how can send ErroCode to related method?

Comment: Where would the error code come from?

Comment: we implement ErrorCode in application's methods. for example when some situation occurred we Throw AbpUserFriendly like this throw new AbpUserFriendlyException("Error occurred 526")

Comment: `AuditLog` already stores exception. Is that insufficient?

Comment: Yes I know. but adding errorCode to AbpAuditLogs in separate field can be better for follow up problems instead of searching in exception field

Comment: Can it be the `CustomData` property, or must it be an `ErrorCode` property?

Comment: It can be `CustomData` to be used for more general purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `AuditingStore` and set `CustomData` to the error code:

```cs
public class MyAuditingStore : AuditingStore
{
    public MyAuditingStore(IRepository<AuditLog, long> auditLogRepository)
        : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
    }

    public override Task SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        auditInfo.CustomData = (auditInfo.Exception as IHasErrorCode)?.Code.ToString();
        return base.SaveAsync(auditInfo);
    }
}
```

You can throw `UserFriendlyException` like this:

```cs
throw new UserFriendlyException(526, "Error occurred 526");
```

Then replace `IAuditingStore` in your module:

```cs
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuditingStore, MyAuditingStore>();
}
```

Comment: another question related to MyAuditingStore. Is it true that we check some condition in SaveAsync Method and for example send email?

Comment: `Is it true that we` → do you mean `Can we`? Yes, you can.

Comment: It's better to do that in an [`IEventHandler<EntityCreatedEventData<AuditLog>>`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events#entity-changes).